# Checking Whether Table Data Exists, Updating / Inserting Into Two Tables & Posting End Outcome

Tags: sql

I am working on my cron system which gathers informaiton via an API call. For most, it has been fairly straight forward, but now I am faced with multiple difficulties, as the API call is dependant on who is making the API request. It runs through each users API Key and certain information will be visible/hidden to them and visaversa to the public.

There are teams, and users are part of teams. A user can stealth their move, however all information will be showed to them and their team, however this will not be visible to their oponent, however both teams share the same id and have access tothe same informaiton, just one can see more of it than the other.

**Defendants Point Of View**

```
"attacks": {
    "12345`": {
        "timestamp": 1645345234,
        "attacker_id": "",
        "attacker_team_id": "",
        "defender_id": 321,
        "defender_team_id": 1,
        "stealthed": 1
    }
}
```

**Attackers Point Of View**

```
"attacks": {
    "12345`": {
        "timestamp": 1645345234,
        "attacker_id": 123,
        "attacker_team_id": 2
        "defender_id": 321,
        "defender_team_id": 1,
        "stealthed": 1,
        "boosters": {
            "fair_fight": 3,
            "retaliation": 1,
            "group_attack": 1
        }
    }
}
```

So, if the defendant's API key is first used, id `12345` will already be in the `team_attacks` table but will not include the `attacker_id` and `attacker_team_id`. For each insert there after, I need to check to see whether the new insert's ID already exist and has any additional information to add to the row.

**Here is the part of my code that loops through the API and obtains the data**, it loops through all the attacks per API Key;

```
else if ($category === "attacks") {
    
    $database = new Database();
    
    foreach($data as $attack_id => $info) {
        
        $database->query('INSERT INTO team_attacks (attack_id, attacker_id, attacker_team_id, defender_id, defender_team_id) VALUES (:attack_id, :attacker_id, :attacker_team_id, :defender_id, :defender_team_id)');
        $database->bind(':attack_id', $attack_id);
        $database->bind(':attacker_id', $info["attacker_id"]);
        $database->bind(':attacker_team_id', $info["attacker_team_id"]);
        $database->bind(':defender_id', $info["defender_id"]);
        $database->bind(':defender_team_id', $info["defender_team_id"]);
        $database->execute();
        
    }
    
}
```

I have also been submitting to the news table, and typically I have simply been submitting `X new entries have been added` or whatnot, however I haven't a clue if there is a way to check during the above if any new entries and any updated entries to produce two news feeds:

- 2 attacks have bee updated.
- 49 new attack information added.

For this part, I was simply counting how many is in the array, but this only works for the first ever upload, I know I cannot simply count the array length on future inserts which require additional checks.

**If The attack_id Does NOT Already Exist** I also need to submit the boosters into another table, for this I was adding them to an array during the above loop and then looping through them to submit those, but this also depends on the above, not simply attempting to upload for each one without any checks. Boosters will share the `attack_id`.

With over 1,000 teams who will potentially have at least one members join my site, I need to be as efficient as this as possible. The API will give the last 100 attacks per call and I want this to be within my cron which collects any new data every 30 seconds, so I need to sort through potentially 100,000.

Comment: It seems like you have several questions listed above (keeping track of new and updated entries, submitting boosters to another table, how to make the process efficient, etc).  It might be good to try to simplify what you are asking for to a single question or post multiple questions.

Comment: @dcp I do not understand how much of this is possible using a single SQL query to be able to break this down into multiple questions. I typically struggle to explain myself and provide not enough detail where I have had help in the past, said more of my intentions, and then people who have helped have had to spend additional time modifying their answer to adapt to my needs, so even if there is a part answer submitted, as long as it can scale to what is required, this will still be realy helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can check conditions when inserting new data using `merge`:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

Depending on the database you are using, the name and syntax of the command might be different. Common names for the command are also `upsert` and `replace`.

But: If you are seeking for high performance and almost-realtimeness, consider using a cache holding critical aggregated data instead of doing the aggregation 100'000 times per minute.

Comment: Thank you for yoru answer @draz, you havev given me a lot to think about. Everything I am doing is self funded and will always be the case, so where I can, I want to be as efficient as possible and not have to upgrade the likes of my servers RAM to perform tasts that I could have written a lot better. I don't know what it takes for the second option, but the first one looks more easier to understand and get to the potnetially the right place. Thanks for this.

Comment: your welcome. using such an `upsert`  prevents you basically of race conditions (but be aware, it depends on the isolation level https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels ). if you want to stick to a db-only approach, a cache table in the db might also be an option. so you would have an all-historic-data-table and an aggregated-data-table which is small and fast. but maybe this is overengineered, you can think about if you actually face serious performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the "answer" you're looking for. The question(s) imply use of a single table for both teams. It's worth considering one table per team for writes to avoid write contention altogether. The two data sets could be combined at query time in order to return "team" results via the API. At scale, you could have another process calculating and storing combined team results in an API-specific cache table that serves the API request.